# How to escape a character

Tags: c, string-formatting

I have this situation where I need to escape a character.
I am trying to form a buffer

```
char buffer[1024]; 
char* x="hello";
char* y="world";
sprintf(buffer,"=%s\n-%s\n ",x,y);
```

My goal here is to get a buffer such as

```
=hello\n-world\n
```

in this exact order. the signs in between such as (=, \n, -) all does a specific action when the buffer is passed into a function.

However, if the present code is printed as shown in the above code I get

```
=hello
-world
```

instead of

```
=hello\n-world\n
```

But this is not desired. How can I achieve the desired result?

Comment: Unclear question. Do you want newline characters in your buffer, or backslash n inside it.

Comment: BTW, you probably mean  `char* x="hello";` so you forgot the `*` and likewise for `y`. So please edit your question to improve it.

Comment: *edited the question
thank you..silly question to ask but learned something.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1079748/694576 and this would make this question merly a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/11244184/694576

Answer (score 7):

You need to escape the backslash, like this : `\\`

```
sprintf(buffer,"=%s\\n-%s\\n ",x,y);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
sprintf(buffer,"=%s\\n-%s\\n ",x,y)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can override any escape sequence by adding a backslash before it.
In this case:

```
sprintf(buffer,"=%s\\n-%s\\n ",x,y);
```

Comment: Please use code formatting (4 spaces) instead of quote formatting for code snippets.

Answer (score 0):

```
        char buffer[1024]; 
        char x="hello";
        char y="world";
        sprintf(buffer,"=%s\n-%s\n ",x,y);
  Add `\` as indicated     ^     ^
```

And also `char x="hello"` you want to store `string` in char variable ,your program will crash.
Change to either of one -

```
    char *x="hello";
```

or

```
    char x[]="hello";
```

Answer (score 0):

`\n` is called a newline escape sequence, which then prints a newline on the console. You need to escape this by prefixing a backslash. For instance

```
sprintf(buffer, "=%s\\n-%s\\n", x, y);
```